# How to implement configuration to use oracle/postgreSQL dataSource with spring+mybatis framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mybatis

Background: spring + mybatis + oracle data source

Requirement: support postgreSQL data source exchange with minimum code change

Example:

Current: controllerA -> ServiceA -> daoA -> A.xml (oracle)

Now need: we can configure use oracele/postgreSQL database source

If configure use postgreSQL:
controllerA -> ServiceA -> daoA -> A.xml (postgreSQL)

More:

Same controllerA、ServiceA for same business logic

Differenct DaoA、A.xml for oracle and postgreSQL mybatis sql implementation

DaoA is better to be same if it can be.

The data and sql logic is the same for oracle and postgreSQL, just need a congfiguration to change to use oracle/postgreSQL implementation.

How to implement it?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55952003/1261766). If it's not the information you are looking for, please add more details.

Comment: @ave this is just what I am looking for, Can I implement it with a annotation way? cuz I have plenty of annotation sql, transfer to xml sql will take much work. I post a question here : [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71149999/how-to-indicate-dabaseid-with-annotation-implementation)

Comment: Thanks @ave, I find the solution : @Options(databaseId = "PostgreSQL") will work

Comment: You can specify `databaseId` in annotations like `@Select`, `@Update`, `@Insert` or `@Delete`. So, for example, you can add two `@Insert` annotations on a single interface method. `@Options(databaseId)` should be used when you need different options for different DB.

Comment: `@Select(value = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table", databaseId="postgresql")
@Select(value = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table", databaseId="oracle")
public int getCount() throws Exception;`

I use databaseId like this, but it gets wrong.
If I remove one `@Select` line, it will be ok.
Anything wrong with my impl? @ave

Comment: What do you mean by "it gets wrong"? Please add the details to the question (stack trace, error message, expected/unexpected results, etc.). Note that if the SQL is the same, you just need one `@Select` with no `databaseId` and it will be used for all DBs.

Comment: Thanks for you kindly help @ave, there is no wrong after mvn clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is on the comments: use databaseIdProvider technique will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).