# How to indicate dabaseId with annotation implementation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mybatis, spring-mybatis

There is a annotation query :

```
@Select("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table")
public String querytableCount() throws Exception;
```

I want to indicate its databaseId to be postgreSQL

If the query is implemented with xml, I can make it with `databaseId="postgresql"`:

```
<select id="querytableCount"   resultType="String" databaseId="postgresql">
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MCT_AGENT
</select>
```

How to implement the requirement base on a annotation implementation?

I have tried `@DatabaseId`:

```
@DatabaseId("PostgreSQL")
@Select("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table")
public String querytableCount() throws Exception;
```

However, @DatabaseId("PostgreSQL") not work.

Answer (score 0):

@Options(databaseId = "PostgreSQL") will work

Need : mybatis 3.5.5 +

Comment: You should specify `databaseId` in `@Select` i.e. `@Select(value="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table", databaseId="PostgreSQL")`.

Comment: @ave Cool, I will try it.